# PHP Convert multidimensional array to a string (LITERALLY)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
[[1,45],[2,23],[3,37],[4,51],[5,18],[6,32],[7,29],[8,45],[9,37],[10,50]]
```

(Those numbers are stored as strings, not int)

What I want is to convert this multidimensional array to a string that teorically is stored  like this:

```
$converted = "[[1,45],[2,23],[3,37],[4,51],[5,18],[6,32],[7,29],[8,45],[9,37],[10,50]]";
```

Literally all the array in one string

currently I have the array stored in a variable named $array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode`,

```
$array = [[1,45],[2,23],[3,37],[4,51],[5,18],[6,32],[7,29],[8,45],[9,37],[10,50]];
echo json_encode($array);
```

And if your numbers is string, you can convert them to int before `json_encode`,

```
$array = [["1", "45"], ["2", "23"], [3, 37], [4, 51], [5, 18], [6, 32], [7, 29], [8, 45], [9, 37], [10, 50]];
echo json_encode(array_map(function ($subArray) {
    return array_map(function ($number) {
        return intval($number);
    }, $subArray);
}, $array));
```

Comment: You can also simplify the entire expression to the following inliner: `echo json_encode(array_map(fn($item) => array_map('intval', $item), $array));`